# Why does str_replace of \n introduce '!' in mail content?

Tags: php

`$mailContent=str_replace("  "," ",$mailContent);
 $mailContent=str_replace("\n"," ",$mailContent);`

Why do the above lines introduce '!' at random points in my mail content?

Input:

http://pastebin.com/7eG6d3SH

Output:

[image: Input :]

Comment: Interesting question. Can you provide examples of in- and output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually had a huge problem with this just yesterday.

Basically, your lines are too long, and out of desperation it's throwing in `!\n` to break it up so it can be transmitted effectively.

Comment: I had this problem for months! Most annoying problem ever, wasn't until I changed the e-mail template that I realised what was causing it! It only took you one day to figure out what was wrong. Damn :( +1

Comment: Hehe, well, I took a lucky guess, threw a `\n` in the middle of my looping template, and it suddenly worked ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the mail() function and not the str_replace(), look at this: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10239796-Exclamation-marks-appearing-when-using-mail()-function

Comment: You should not link to an off-site resource without at least quoting something relevant in your answer. Imagine if that server exploded tomorrow, your answer would be useless. Not that it matters, because the thread you linked to only has a person with a similar question, not an answer. https://xkcd.com/979/